# Creating and using Arguments in WorkFlowDesigner rehosted WF4.5

Tags: arguments, workflow-foundation

I can create arguments through the designer using the **Arguments** tab when editing activity XAML files. I can then pass arguments when invoking the workflow. This works fine.

However, in a rehosted WorkflowDesigner we do not have the **Arguments** tab (I wouldn't like my users modifying the arguments list anyway). So I'd like to **WorkflowDesigner.Load()** a workflow that has the arguments already set up, as a template from which to build workflows. Users could then still access the arguments while designing the workflow, perhaps on which to base FlowDecision conditions etc.

Is that at all possible?
Should I rather be using Dynamic Arguments for this purpose?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to post: [Show an activity into the designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648672/show-an-activity-into-the-designer) I was able to create an ActivityBuilder with properties:

```
Properties = 
{ 
    new DynamicActivityProperty { Name = "Account", Type = typeof(InArgument<AccountModel>) }
}
```

And **Load()** it in a **WorkflowDesigner**.

This this means that I can now force the AccountModel argument into any user created workflow.

I hope this comes in handy to anyone stuck with the same problem.

Comment: This is what I was looking for also. Thanks for posting!